# How can I draw a layout in Xamarin Forms similar to this image?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

This is Layout I'd like to draw in my ContentPage(ListView is just added)

[image]

I tried to use a Grid with a row and two columns in which to place two BoxView inside the first one a further Grid with 3 rows and two columns for the Label in the second Box a Label but the result was disappointing

Comment: Share what you've got so far with your grid try. It pretty possible, for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few options.  You can use `Grid` with `Margin` and `Padding` properties so the contents won't be too close to one another.  Or you can use `AbsoluteLayout` or `RelativeLayout` so you can position every single elements as the way you want to.  You can read the [documentation for layouts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/) for more information.